# How can I make a nested query more efficient?

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python, time-complexity

Lets say I'm having 4 tables '`A(id, type, protocol), B(id, A_id, info), C(id, B_id, details) and D(id, C_id, port_info)`. Table `A` and Table `B` are connected via foreign key `id` from Table `A` and `A_id` from Table `B`. Similarly, Table `B` and Table`C` are connected via foreign key `id` from Table`B` and `B_id` from Table `C`, and in the same way , Table `C` and Table `D` are also connected.

Now, I want to get `port_info` from Table `D` of all the `protocols` from Table `A`.
I know one method whose time complexity is `O(n^4)`, which I'm using currently. The method is as follow :

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="mydb")
cur = db.cursor() 
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM A")

A_results = cur.fetchall()
for A_row in A_results : 
    id      = A_row[0]
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM B WHERE A_id = %d " % (id ))
    B_results = cur.fetchall()

    for B_row in B_results : 
        id      = B_row[0]
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM C WHERE B_id = %d " % (id ))
        c_results = cur.fetchall()

        for C_row in C_results : 
            id      = C_row[0]
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM D WHERE C_id = %d " % (id ))
            D_results = cur.fetchall()

            for D_row in D_results : 
                print "Port = " + str(port)
```

But this method takes `O(n^4)`, so is there any efficient way in terms of `time complexity` , that can solve this problem.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL (or indeed any SQL) 101. See JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute it in a single `JOIN` query and let MySQL do the necessary optimizations while handling large data sets (which, after all, is what the database is best at), providing your application with a single result set. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT A.protocol, D.port_info
FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.A_id
       JOIN C ON B.id = C.B_id
       JOIN D ON C.id = D.C_id
ORDER BY protocol
```

...and then use your cursor to go through that single resultset.

Comment: And what will be the time-complexity of this?

Comment: O(n) (at the Python level), because you're using one loop over a single returned resultset rather than four. If this question is for academic purposes you may also want to consider MySQL's internal handling of such joins and how B-trees work. If it's not for academic purposes but is for real work, then the big-O notation is far, far less significant than the penalty of nested I/O operations to the DB.

Comment: So, in other words, you mean to say that I shouldnt be using JOIN operations when working real-time?

Comment: The other way around. You shouldn't use nested application code to issue queries based on the outer code, if you can use a `JOIN` to run it in a single query. I/O is the blocking factor, not query size, so if you run queries in a loop you've to deal with the I/O overhead of setting up and executing each query. In other words, the solution in the answer is possibly orders of magnitude faster than that in the question in real terms, not due to the CPU cost of the O(n^4) algorithm but due to the I/O cost of running nested queries.